# Как сделать выпадающее меню на всю ширину, когда родитель вложен в контейнер?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap4, navigation

Есть `bootstrap` меню навигации. 
Как сделать так, чтобы выпадающее меню было на всю ширину страницы независимо от разрешения экрана?

Сложность заключается в том, что родительское меню `nav` находится в классе `container` и ограничена по ширине. Можно ли решить с помощью стилей?

**ВАЖНОЕ УТОЧНЕНИЕ:** фон распространяется за родителя, а отступ начинается вместе с родителем!

**Код** в [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/v0ty759e/)

```css
.navbar, .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #343a40;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: не очень понятна суть вопроса, если проблема в том что container имеет фиксированную ширину, тогда есть альтернатива, класс: cantainer-fluid он резиновый.

Comment: @Эдик Билый суть простая: родитель фиксируется на ширину контейнера, а выпадающий список должен занимать всю ширину экрана на любом разрешении, т.е. выходить за пределы родителя.